# How do I determine the new language of a webpage translated by Google translate?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-translate

I have a need to display a disclaimer if the user of my webpage chooses to translate using Google translate.
How can I determine if the page has been translated and what language it was translated to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can detect it by looking at the URL. If a page is translated, the URL will start with `http://translate.googleusercontent.com/` and the language is specified by the `tl` request parameter.

Another option is to check if the URL is different from the expected one (your website), and display a disclaimer if so.

Answer (score 2):

You can look for requests for your page from the Google Translate domain, that's a good hint that someone is using Google translate. But then you'd have to keep up with all possible domains they use, and they could change.

And then you might also want to worry about people using Bing Translate, or any other service out there...

It might be easier to put up a generic disclaimer for all users regardless of whether they use a translator or not? It would be a bit of a pain, but if you absolutely have to show a disclaimer for some reason then it's the only way to guarantee it is always shown,